# Как сделать чтобы заработал мой пример?

Tags: python

Установил библиотеку [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/archive/p/boilerpipe/) для python 3.7

Для теста решил проверить такой простенький пример:

```
 from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
 extractor = Extractor(extractor='ArticleExtractor', convertStrings=False ,url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
 print(extractor.getText())
```

При запуске кода выходит такая ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py:210: UserWarning: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deprecated: convertStrings was not specified when starting the JVM. The default
behavior in JPype will be False starting in JPype 0.8. The recommended setting
for new code is convertStrings=False.  The legacy value of True was assumed for
this session. If you are a user of an application that reported this warning,
please file a ticket with the developer.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  """)

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: Используете в качестве интерпретатора Jython?

Comment: @gil9red,Jython ? В качестве интерпретатора у меня  python 3.7 редактор кода pycharm

Comment: Тогда, у вас скорее всего стандартная реализация на с++ -- cython. Меня в ошибке смутило, что там виртуальная машина java (JVM) упоминается. Но эта зависимость к java идет от JPype

Comment: @gil9red,Разве ? Вообще библиотека boilerpipe  нуждается в Jpype

Comment: @gil9red,может эта ошибка возникает из-за того что я не импортировал Jpype ?

Comment: Так написано на странице https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe среди зависимостей. У вас jpype стоит, иначе в пути не было того модуля: `Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jpype`

Comment: @gil9red,точно ) Я что-то не обратил внимание на это.Как вы думаете в чем тогда проблема ?

Comment: Введите в консоли `echo %JAVA_HOME%` должен вывестись путь к папке с java, например `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`

Comment: @gil9red,в консоле винды или пайчарма ?

Comment: Без разницы -- у меня и там, и там работает эта команда

Comment: @gil9red,я нашел путь к папке с Java.Какие дальнейшие указания ?)

Comment: Попробуйте следующий совет: удалите текущий JPype и поставьте старую версию 0.6.3 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56755564/5909792

Comment: @gil9red,установил версию Jpype 0.6.3.После зашел запустить код.Теперь вместо сообщения об ошибке выходит следующие `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Comment: Похоже на https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype/issues/239

Comment: @gil9red,посмотрел почитал.Благодарю за ссылку но это не то.Там про Linux в основном говорится. А на счет ошибки которая возникает при смешении 32-битных и 64-битных сред. Это я проверил и не из-за этого возникает эта ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял в чем ошибка.Библиотека использует старый API для Jpypi, и если вылезает этот ворнинг.Решение было установить Jpype версии 0.6.3.

После я удалил библиотеку Boilerpipe.И установил более новый fork библиотеки [boilerpipe](https://pypi.org/project/boilerpy3/)

После чего все заработало !

**P.S:** Отдельная благодарность этому [человеку года](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red)